# Navbar donesn't Collapse Boostrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

when i open my html file i don't find the collapse button on the navbar. The button for collapsing does not appear
here is my html code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BoostUp - Boostez vos projets</title>
        <link href="/assets/css/boostrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/heroes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/assets/img/logo.png" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                BoostUp
              </a>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Accueil</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Référencement</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Posts</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
<script src="./assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/booststrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/firestart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ps : i'm on bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the toggler button.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

[Toggler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#toggler)